# <font size="+1"><i> "+1" meaning in ASP.NET site

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms

can someone explain me what this line "" is supposed to do in the ASP.NET Web Forms code.

```
<tr>
    <td align="center" colspan="3">
        <font size="+1">
           <i>
              <asp:Literal EnableViewState="false" ID="lOrderList" Text="Orders" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="lOrderListResource" />
           </i>
         </font>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: It seems that you are not right, but anyway thanks for trying;)

Answer (score 2):

The `size` attribute ranges from 1 - 7.  Using `size="+1"` or `size="-2"` actually sets the size relative to the current base.  By default most browsers and sites will use `size=3`, so `size="+1"` is equivalent of setting `size="4"`.

- `Size="+1"` will increase the size by one over the base.
- `Size="+2"` will increase the size by two.
- `Size="-1"` will decrease the size by one. etc...

Please see the MDN entry for the [font](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font) tag `Size` attribute:

> This attribute specifies the font size as either a numeric or relative
>   value. Numeric values range from 1 to 7 with 1 being the smallest and
>   3 the default. It can be defined using a relative value, like +2 or
>   -3, which set it relative to the value of the size attribute of the  element, or relative to 3, the default value, if none does
>   exist.

```html
<font >Default size</font> <br/>
<font size="+1">Using size="+1" => Next size larger than default</font> 
<font size="4" color="blue">Using size="4" is same as size="+1"</font> <br/>
<font size="-1">Using size="-1" => Previous size smaller than default</font> 
<font size="2" color="blue">Using size="2" is same as size="-1"</font>
```

**Please note:** The `<font>` tag is obsolete and you should avoid using it if possible.

<sup>Note: on my browser `size="4"` and `size="+1"` display the same size, might be different for your browser/setup.</sup>

Comment: Thank you, It answers my queston compleletely. I also read that this parameter is obsolete and people do not reccoment to use it in the code. Unfortunatelly I am currently working with very old one.

Comment: @PiotrP excellent, I'm glad I could help.

Comment: @PiotrP you could probably replace `font` with `span`, something like this maybe: `<span style="font-size: 18px">...</span>`